# How to update a package in ubuntu-builder which requires system reboot?

Tags: live-cd, customization, chroot, customizer

I am trying to create a customized ubuntu live cd using `ubuntu-builder`. I was following this perticular answer:

[How to customize live Ubuntu CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-live-ubuntu-cd)

If I try to update a package which requires system restart (such as kernel) in **desktop-mode(GUI-mode)** using **synaptic**, it installs the package but then the session indicator turns red
& says `restart to complete update`.

[image]

But since its a virtual chrooted environment running on `xephyr` , I can not perform restart (if I try it just hangs).

So how do I perform a system restart within chroot to complete the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't be necessary. The update installs the new kernel, create a new boot image and update the GRUB config to point to the new kernel ready for the next boot, that is the maiden boot of the new ISO.

In other words, *ignore* the restart message.